# Align various objects/items vertically with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am building a temporary site, and I want to align (to middle) the logo and the menu items vertically, but I am unable to achieve success.

Here is my current HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <a class="logo" href="/index.html"><img class="logo" src="/images/logo.png"></a>

        <a class="menu" href="/whatever.html">Menu Item 1</a>
        <a class="menu" href="/whatever.html">Menu Item 2</a>
        <a class="menu" href="/whatever.html">Menu Item 3</a>
        <a class="menu" href="/whatever.html">Menu Item 4</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my current CSS code:

```
.header {
    display: block;
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I have removed all other styling, like colors, to simplify.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: so you want the logo to be vertically aligned?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BatN4/?

Comment: @Markasoftware Yes, I want everything to be vertically aligned with everything else, no matter the height.

Comment: @j08691 If I use position:absolute then the whole page is taken up and I cannot see my other content.

Comment: Then perhaps you should post a code example that's more representative of your actual content and what you want the final product to look like.

Comment: Sorry i posted it as an answer, i was asking if it was something like this http://jsfiddle.net/KSL7j/20/ ?

Comment: @j08691 Code is updated with Lorem Ipsum. Structure will be very similar but I have very little content yet.

Comment: @alexoulu Sorry, but unfortunately those menu items are underneath each other, not next to each other.

Answer (score 2):

according to w3: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#vertical

CSS level 2 doesn't have a property for centering things vertically. There will probably be one in CSS level 3. But even in CSS2 you can center blocks vertically, by combining a few properties. The trick is to specify that the outer block is to be formatted as a table cell, because the contents of a table cell can be centered vertically.

so the code is really simple

```
#container{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 200px;
}
```

here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/4PJUr/

Comment: I can't get this to work with more than one item to be aligned vertically with each other.

Comment: i am not clear what you mean. can you give some code to show your requirement.

Comment: I would like the logo and menu items in my code above to be vertically aligned with each other. The logo is larger than the menu text, so they need to be in the middle of the logo.

Comment: I love the way you explained

Comment: I assume that is supposed to be sarcasm? I had given up on this thread.